# How do I read Bluetooth headset name?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, headset

I want to read the bluetooth headset name.

I managed to rout the sound trough the headset and to get the current route for the `kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute`.

I was not able to find any documentation how to read the headset name. Any link, advice or code is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read the name of the device as it is written in Settings/Bluetooth.
However, you can access to the name written in the device (which sometimes is different, I've seen this case) :

```
EASessionController = [EADSessionController sharedController];
    _accessoryList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories]];

    for (EAAccessory *key in _accessoryList)
    {
            NSLog(@"Name : %@", key.name);
    }
```

More information at [EAAccessory](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/EAAccessory_class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

Comment: This will read Bluetooth headsets? Because i have tried it and it does not seem to work. And my Bluetooth is recognized by other apps. 
I have also read that the EAAccessoryManager will return only the made for iPod deviceces

Comment: Yes, it works for headsets (I've done it with headset and a few toys), but only with Made for iPhone/iPod devices.